# Scanner use to search text area.

Tags: string

my application allows me to open a text file into a text area to read some raw data. Then I need to allow the user to click a button that will search for a string of words that will bring the selection open in another text area.

almost like scanning textarea1 and bringing certain words/strings into text area 2.

For example in my raw data there are key identifiers. I need to seperate those identifiers and make them visible in text area 2.

Hope I make sense, I'm looking for some guidance.

Thanks All

Comment: Have you attempted this is code yet? If you have, post what you've got into your question so we can see where you are at.

Comment: Well I attempted it trying to use scanner. But not sure how to get it to read another text area opposed to a file. I thought that might be the easy bit but no such luck. The search bit I am at a complete loss.So i don't really have a code output as I keep removing it to start a fresh.

Comment: Basically you are going to need to implement a listener on your search button which will scan the text in the textarea. The searching part will require you to compare some strings manually. There are many ways to do this, but you will have to do it manually.

Comment: I have currently set it back to this that allows when I click the button to carry the whole output to another text area. Kind of pointless at the moment but I was hoping to modify it to get the data i required.   


        NewJFrame1 s = new NewJFrame1();
        NewJFrame1.jTextArea1JF1.setText(this.jTextArea1.getText());
        
        s.setVisible(true);

Comment: It will be easier if you post your code as a code block in your question, not in a comment. Post all you have done.